Instance of chain rule in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds after implicit function theorem
I have a question about a use of the chain rule in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds. I believe this is just some basic confusion I have with the notation.
Let $f:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$ be $C^1$ in an open set containing $(a,b)$ and $f(a,b)=0$. Under some additional conditions, the implicit function theorem guarantees there is a differentiable function $g$ such that $f(x,g(x))=0$ for $x$ in an open set containing $a$. In Spivak's book, he then differentiates a component of $f$ in the equation $f^i(x,g(x))=0$, that is, he takes $D_j$ on both sides and gets $$0=D_jf^i\left(x,g\left(x\right)\right)+\sum _{\alpha =1}^mD_{n+\alpha }f^i\left(x,g\left(x\right)\right)\cdot D_j g^{\alpha}\left(x\right),\quad i,j=1,\ldots, m.\tag1$$
I just don't understand why $j$ ranges as it does. Suppose $n=1$ and $m=2$, and then apparently we can have $j=2$. This makes little sense to me, as we have $f^1(x,g^1(x),g^2(x))$ and $f^2(x,g^1(x),g^2(x))$, two functions that depend only on $x$. We get $$\frac{df^1}{dx}=\frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f^1}{\partial g^1}\frac{\partial g^1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f^1}{\partial g^2}\frac{\partial g^2}{\partial x},$$ and $$\frac{df^2}{dx}=\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial g^1}\frac{\partial g^1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial g^2}\frac{\partial g^2}{\partial x}.$$ These two expressions are equal to the formula, however, the first term is only ever $D_1 f^i(x,g(x))$, or? In other words, I don't see how $j=2$ in that first term.
